# Do you know what WebDAV HTTP Verbs are used by MS Word?

Tags: webdav

We have a WebDAV servlet in place and are starting to get MS Word up and running against it.  We have OPTIONS and PROPFIND and GET.  Do you know of other verbs that Word will be requesting?

Answer (score 3):

According to RFC 2518, you will have to support LOCK, UNLOCK, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, COPY, MOVE, MKCOL verbs.

Comment: RFC 4918 is the current one. AFAIR, MS Office won't do COPY, MOVE, PROPPATCH or MKCOL. But you'll need LOCK and UNLOCK to get read/write access working.

Comment: @Julian: MS Office does PROPPATCH, here is the example: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><D:propertyupdate xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:Z="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:"><D:set><D:prop><Z:Win32CreationTime>Wed, 21 Nov 2012 21:40:59 GMT</Z:Win32CreationTime><Z:Win32LastAccessTime>Fri, 23 Nov 2012 21:13:04 GMT</Z:Win32LastAccessTime><Z:Win32LastModifiedTime>Fri, 23 Nov 2012 21:13:04 GMT</Z:Win32LastModifiedTime><Z:Win32FileAttributes>00000020</Z:Win32FileAttributes></D:prop></D:set></D:propertyupdate>

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save documents to server from MS office only OPTIONS, PROPFIND and GET would not be enough.

Here is the list that you need to implement: GET, HEAD, LOCK, OPTIONS, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, UNLOCK

RFC 2518 is replaced by RFC 4918.